# Singleton for webdriver instance in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, singleton

Is there a reasonable way to create a singleton for the webDriver in javascript?

Reading through some documents about them and it seems in js it's somewhat of a headache to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

const SingletonFactory = (function(){
    function singletonClass() {
    }
    let driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();
    driver.manage().setTimeouts({implicit: (100000)});

    Object.freeze(chromeOptions);
    Object.freeze(driver);

    return {
        getInstance: function(){
            if (driver == null) {
                driver = new singletonClass();
                // Hide the constructor so the returned object can't be new'd...
                driver.constructor = null;
            }
            return driver;
        }
   };
})();
```

That's the answers code.